# Is there a way to get the title of a React FullCalendar?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, fullcalendar

I'm working on a calendar using FullCalendar from [fullcalendar.io](https://fullcalendar.io/). Here is my code :

```
import React from "react"
import FullCalendar from "@fullcalendar/react"
import listPlugin from "@fullcalendar/list"
import dayGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/daygrid"
import timeGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/timegrid"
import interactionPlugin from "@fullcalendar/interaction"
import frLocale from "@fullcalendar/core/locales/fr"

const Calendar = (props) => {


const calendarOptions = {
  events: data.events.length ? data.events : [],
  eventColor: variables.promoter,
  plugins: [interactionPlugin, dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, listPlugin],
  initialView: "dayGridMonth",
  headerToolbar: {
    start: "prevYear,prev,next,nextYear",
    center: "title",
    end: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay",
  },
  timeZone: "Europe/Paris",
  eventTimeFormat: { hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit", hour12: false },
  editable: true,
  locale: frLocale,

  eventResizableFromStart: true,

  dragScroll: true,

  dayMaxEvents: 2,

  navLinks: true,

  ...

  };
return <FullCalendar {...calendarOptions} />;
  };
  
  export default Calendar;
```

Anyway the code works, and it gives me a calendar [as follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVlxm.png).

So my question is : Is it possible to store the calendar title into a variable so that I can use it the way I want?

I have already looked at the [fullcalendar documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs), but still don't have any solution...
Thank you by advance for any help!

Comment: When you say the title, do you mean the bit which shows the current month? You can get fullCalendar to tell you the current date, or range of dates, which the calendar is dispaying. If you [fetch the current view object](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-view) it contains the start and end dates of the currently-displayed view.

Comment: Thanks! I wanna know if there is a props in FullCalendar that contains the current calendar title or a way to access it.

Comment: Yes I know, you already explained that, and I asked a question about what you meant exactly, which you haven't answered. Please clarify by answering that, and/or explain why the suggestion I made in the comment wouldn't be helpful for you. There is no property which can _directly_ access the title, but since (by default) it's basically just some generated text showing the current date range of the calendar, you can get the same information in the way I described above.

Comment: I wanna store the current calendar title (on the screenshot, it would be "février 2022") as a string

Comment: Ok. Well my first comment explains how you can get the date information which is used to generate that title. You cannot get the title directly from the fullCalendar API. You have to get the current view object and extract the dates from it, (and then of course you can format them however you wish).

Comment: Ok thanks, I am going to try it. Sorry if I sometimes have lack of english understanding.